# Complex Nested IF AND Formula Being Written to Sheet by VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I currently have a complex formula that I am trying to place into a cell via VBA.  The current working formula (in cell BP2) is as follows:

```
'=IF(X2="No Bonus",1,
'IF(AND(((AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12))>=50,AD2="N"),5,
'IF(AND(((AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12))>=40,AD2="N"),4,
'IF(AND(((AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12))>=30,AD2="N"),2,
'IF(AND(((AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12))>=20,AD2="N"),1,
'IF(AND(((AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12))>0,AD2="N"),0.5,
'IF(AND(((AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12))>=20,AD2="Y"),1,
'IF(AND(((AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12))>=15,AD2="Y"),2,
'IF(AND(((AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12))>=0,AD2="Y"),0.3,0)))))))))
```

I am placing the code in a variable range below existing data in Column BP.  My code is currently as follows:

```
Dim LastRowExisting As Long
Dim LastRowNew As Long

LastRowExisting = Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Range("CE1").Value 'LastRow of Existing data stored here by macro earlier
LastRowNew = Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'requires Column A "Source" is always populated on all lines    

Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Range("BP" & LastRowExisting + 1 & ":" & "BP" & LastRowNew).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-44]=""No Bonus"",""1"", _
IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=50,RC[-38]=""N"",""5"", _
IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=40,RC[-38]=""N"",""4"", _
IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=30,RC[-38]=""N"",""2"", _
IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=20,RC[-18]=""N"",""1"", _
IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=0,RC[-38]=""N"",""0.5"", _
IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=20,RC[-38]=""Y"",""1"", _
IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=15,RC[-38]=""Y"",""2"", _
IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=0,RC[-38]=""Y"",""0.3"",""0"")))))))))"
```

I am getting a run time error '1004' "Application-defined or object defined error" on the formula line.  I have tried to see if my line breaks are the issue by putting this in one long line but I am still getting the same error.

I realize this is likely a syntax issue but I'm struggling to see what is off.  I know this is a less than ideal (ie. ugly) solution, but given where this takes place in a larger macro, I'm hoping to make this formula method work.

If it helps; the general idea is to end up with a value (5,4,2,1,.5, etc) based on two criteria.  The first is if `(AG-AF+1)/(365/12)` is in a certain range and the second is a simple `Y` or `N` flag in `Column AD`. Ex. `(AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12) = 45` and `AD2 = N` then I'd expect `BP2 = 4`.

Cheers!

Comment: That's a good UDF candidate - it's basically just a `Select Case`.

Comment: `""5""` are these quotes around the numeric return values required ? The original formula had none in those locations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing as Select Case is probably a good idea but remember the macro recorder can be your friend here. Simply record entering the formula in cell BP2 and copy the output after the ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1:

```
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-44]=""No Bonus"",1,IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=50,RC[-38]=""N""),5,IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=40,RC[-38]=""N""),4,IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=30,RC[-38]=""N""),2,IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=20,RC[-38]=""N""),1,IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>0,RC[-38]=""N""),0.5,IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=2" & _
        "0,RC[-38]=""Y""),1,IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=15,RC[-38]=""Y""),2,IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=0,RC[-38]=""Y""),0.3,0)))))))))" & _
        ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code this way, where each line is a separate string in quotation marks.

```
Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Range("BP" & LastRowExisting + 1 & ":" & "BP" & _
    LastRowNew).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-44]=""No Bonus"",""1"", " & _
    "IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=50,RC[-38]=""N"",""5"", " & _
    "IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=40,RC[-38]=""N"",""4"", " & _
    "IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=30,RC[-38]=""N"",""2"", " & _
    "IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=20,RC[-18]=""N"",""1"", " & _
    "IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=0,RC[-38]=""N"",""0.5"", " & _
    "IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=20,RC[-38]=""Y"",""1"", " & _
    "IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=15,RC[-38]=""Y"",""2"", " & _
    "IF(AND(((RC[-35]-RC[-36]+1)/(365/12))>=0,RC[-38]=""Y"",""0.3"",""0"")))))))))"
```

The line-continuation character (an underscore) can be used between strings, as in the example at [How to Break and Combine Statements in Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-break-and-combine-statements-in-code).

Comment: Scenography Thanks for the link, I had actually looked through there and tried a few things to clean up syntax on single lines vs line breaks.  Unfortunately the code in your answer also errors `Run-time 1004`

Answer (score 0):

## Typing & Typing & Typing

Open your workbook, open VBE, insert a new module (or use an existing one) and paste the following code into the module:

```
Option Explicit

Function Nested(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, _
    Range3 As Range, Range4 As Range) As Single

'**** Customize BEGIN ******************
  'NOCase
  Const cStrSearch As String = "No Bonus"
  Const cSglYes As Single = 1
  'Period
  Const cDays As Integer = 365
  Const cMonths As Integer = 12
  'YesNo
  Const cStrYes As String = "Y"
  Const cStrNo As String = "N"
  'Title1 Source
  Const cSglN1 As Single = 50
  Const cSglN2 As Single = 40
  Const cSglN3 As Single = 30
  Const cSglN4 As Single = 20
  Const cSglN5 As Single = 0
  'Title1 Target
  Const cSglNA1 As Single = 5
  Const cSglNA2 As Single = 4
  Const cSglNA3 As Single = 2
  Const cSglNA4 As Single = 1
  Const cSglNA5 As Single = 0.5
  'Title2 Source
  Const cSglY1 As Single = 20
  Const cSglY2 As Single = 15
  Const cSglY3 As Single = 0
  'Title2 Target
  Const cSglYA1 As Single = 1
  Const cSglYA2 As Single = 2
  Const cSglYA3 As Single = 0.3
'**** Customize END ********************

  If Range1.Value2 = cStrSearch Then
    Nested = cSglYes
    Exit Function
  End If

  Nested = (Range4.Value2 - Range3.Value2) / cDays / cMonths

  Select Case UCase(Range2.Text) 'Remove 'Ucase' function for case-sensitive
    Case cStrNo
      Select Case Nested
        Case Is >= cSglN1: Nested = cSglNA1
        Case Is >= cSglN2: Nested = cSglNA2
        Case Is >= cSglN3: Nested = cSglNA3
        Case Is >= cSglN4: Nested = cSglNA4
        Case Is > cSglN5: Nested = cSglNA5
        Case Else
          Nested = 0 'Change if necessary
      End Select
    Case cStrYes
      Select Case Nested
        Case Is >= cSglY1: Nested = cSglYA1
        Case Is >= cSglY2: Nested = cSglYA2
        Case Is >= cSglY3: Nested = cSglYA3
        Case Else
          Nested = 0 'Change if necessary
      End Select
    Case Else
      Nested = 0 'Change if necessary
  End Select

'=IF(X2="No Bonus",1,
'IF(AND(((AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12))>=50,AD2="N"),5,
'IF(AND(((AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12))>=40,AD2="N"),4,
'IF(AND(((AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12))>=30,AD2="N"),2,
'IF(AND(((AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12))>=20,AD2="N"),1,
'IF(AND(((AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12))>0,AD2="N"),0.5,
'IF(AND(((AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12))>=20,AD2="Y"),1,
'IF(AND(((AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12))>=15,AD2="Y"),2,
'IF(AND(((AG2-AF2+1)/(365/12))>=0,AD2="Y"),0.3,0)))))))))
End Function
```

Close VBE and in the worksheet (Excel) in **any** cell in the second row (except `X2`, `AD2`, `AF2`, `AG2`) (e.g. `BP2` as you mentioned) use the following formula:

```
=NESTED($X2,$AD2,$AF2,$AG2)
```

Copy/Paste the formula down as far as you need it.

Comment: VBasic2008 I appreciate the alternative method here.  I am not testing and implementing because the "formula put in cells via vba" is part of a long hands off automated process.  I'll try out your method the next time I'm doing something similar!

Comment: Thanks for the credit although I don't deserve it since I only now have realized that I have miss understood the question. Sorry.